# Annealing epsilon in epsilon-greedy policy when using DQN

Tags: reinforcement-learning

When using DQN, I was told that it's better to fill up the entire replay memory before learning. I am wondering how to anneal the epsilon if I use epsilon-greedy policy. Say the replay memory size is 10000 so the agent should run 10000 steps before learning. Should I start to anneal the epsilon during the 10000 steps or after the learning starts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of reducing progressively epsilon parameter in a epsilon-greedy policy is to move from a more explorative policy to a more exploitative one. This step, only make sense when the agent has learnt something, i.e., when it has some knowledge to exploit.

So, in short, you should start annealing after learning starts.

Comment: You reduce the epsilon parameter to have a more exploitative policy.